# CSS: Start Animation on hover, then never stop again

Tags: html, css, animation, hover, transition

I am new to CSS-Animation, so maybe the answer for you is easy. But I couldn't find an answer here yet.

I want an Element to start an animation on hover and then never end. It's for an art project because practically it doesn't make any sense.

What I have got is: A little circle, when on hover it starts getting bigger and bigger. And I want that animation to continue endlessly (or fake it like endlessly with transition: 100000s or sth like that).

Any idea how to manage that?

What I have got is this:

```css
.circle{
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transition: 1000s;
}

.circle:hover{
  transform: scale(8000);
}

.circle:hover{
  transform: scale(8000);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Thank you very much already.

Comment: First of all, a _transition_ and an _animation_ are different things. Second, you can not really do this using CSS - `:hover` only applies as long _as_ you hover, afterwards the element will fall back to its “default” formatting. You need to use JavaScript to trigger this - add a class to the element on first mouseover, that triggers this transition.

Comment: Do you want endless animation while the mouse cursor is on the circle? When the cursor is removed from the circle, the animation disappears. Right?

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys. Now I can understand it better! Solutions of Mispell, George and  Hypér function very well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .circle{
            background-color: orange;
            border-radius: 10px;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            margin-top: 10%;
            margin-left: 50%;
            transition: 1s;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="circle" onmouseover="changeScale(this)"></div>
    <script>
        function changeScale(circle){
            circle.style.transform = 'scale(80)';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no need to use JS.

Comment: @George, I truly hope you understand that your answer, too, uses JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

I changed the `.circle:hover` to a new class called "circleAnimation". Then, I gave the circle an onmouseenter event that adds it to the class (since the JavaScript is only one line, I entered it right into value of the onmouseenter event).

This is what the result looks like:

```css
.circle {
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transition: 1000s;
}

.circleAnimation {
    transform: scale(8000);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle" onmouseenter="event.target.classList.add('circleAnimation')"></div>
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you very much this is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

I think it can help you.

```css
.circle {
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transition: 1000s;
}

.animate {
    transform: scale(8000);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle" onmouseenter="event.target.classList.add('animate')"></div>
```

You can also use `onmouseover` instead of `onmouseenter`.